# loadFromJSON iText Issue fabricJS

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

To add text on `canvas` I am using below code,

```
var objtext = new fabric.IText(t);
var textParameters  = {
   top:200,
   left:200,
   width:200,
   height:200,
   fontSize:50,
   fontWeight:'normal',
   fontFamily:'Arial',
   fill:'black',
   selectable:true,
   radius:0,
   spacing:20,
   isCurved:isCurvedText,
   ElementParameters:{ElementType:'text',colors:'black'}
};
objtext.set(textParameters);
canvas.add(objtext);
objtext.setControlsVisibility(HideControls);
canvas.renderAll();
canvas.setActiveObject(objtext);
```

When I use `toJSON()` and use that json for `loadFromJSON`. It throws error

> this.text undefined. text parameter is missing.

Please suggest change

Comment: Please don't use the [iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itext*) tag when your question is totally unrelated to iText®, the open source PDF library. iText is a trademarked name! Please don't create confusion by using that name in a different context.

Comment: What is `t`, `basicParameters`, `isCurvedText` and `HideControls` here ?

Comment: I update question basicParameters = textParameters, t is variable in which I have pass text string to set. HideControls  is for draw control of canvas

Comment: Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/zq1pnxu5/). Are you using like this?

Comment: yes, but doing things on click of button.

Comment: Then, Create a fiddle/snippet stating your problem, so I can help.